# R language - heat maps

Tags: r, graphics, heatmap

I'm trying to build a heat map using R. I have a matrix of values (percentage) like:

```
<p>0 5 0 0 25 30</p>
<p>0 0 0 10 0 0</p>
<p>10 15 65 65 70</p>
```

and so on.
What I want to get - a heat map where the same values (across the whole matrix) would be represented by the same colour. But I still get a map where the colour for the zero value in the first row differs from the colour for the zero value in the second row etc.
Command that I used to build a heat map is:

```
my_heatmap <- heatmap(my_heat_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col = colors_01, margins=c(5,10))
```

UPD: Sorry, I found an answer.

Comment: was it indeed `scale="none"` ?

Comment: PS I think you're allowed (even encouraged) to answer your own question, if you figure it out yourself ...

Comment: Yeah, exactly scale="none". Apologize for this question.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should try the `scale="none"` argument.

A reproducible example would have been helpful ...

```
z <- outer(1:10,1:10,"+")
heatmap(z,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA)
heatmap(z,Rowv=NA,Colv=NA,scale="none")
```

`heatmap` may qualify as the most annoying R graphics function because of its use of `layout`, which makes it impossible to arrange the plots on the page in any sensible way ... (`filled.contour` and the plots from the `hexbin` package share similar annoyances).
[image]

Comment: A good reason to use image() directly instead. Also there is now rasterImage() to avoid the underlying rect calls.